# Equal height flex items in flex columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make it so list items in a column have equal height inside their list.

Here is what I have:

```
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>

ol {
   min-height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

ol li { 
   flex: 1;
}
```

I have tried: I have attempted to follow this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/ to no avail. I think the trouble has to do with *having to set height: 100% to every single parent element all the way to html*. Can that be right?

My list is deeply nested and setting all those heights breaks the layout. I would prefer to work only with fluid heights.

I have also tried: accomplishing this with just divs instead of a list. Still, no luck.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you used the code from the csstricks site verbatim? You need some vendor prefixes to make it work properly everywhere. Apologies if you just didn't include them brevity!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're using a percentage height on the flex container...

```
ol { min-height: 100%; }
```

... you need to also [define a height for the parent and root elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276).

**HTML** (no changes)

```
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { height: 90%; } /* NEW; needed for child percentage heights to work; 
                              set at 90% just for demo purposes */
ol {
   min-height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

ol li { 
   flex: 1;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kzL4305k/1/

> I think the trouble has to do *with having to set `height: 100%` to every
>   single parent element all the way to html*. Can that be right?

Yes, that is correct. If you use percentage heights you need to specify the height for every single parent all the way up to the root element (`html`). I've explained the reason for this here:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

> My list is deeply nested and setting all those heights breaks the
>   layout. I would prefer to work only with fluid heights.

You don't need to set the height for parent elements if you don't use percentages. Try using `min-height` in pixels on flex containers, then letting `flex-grow: 1` deal with the height issue for flex items.

Comment: How about using `100vh`?

Comment: @deltab, `vh` is definitely an option, if you want the element's height to be relative to the viewport.

Comment: Thank you @Michael_B - that was a great breakdown and clarification. I opted to set a pixel height on the list's parent because, for my project, it would affect fewer things and decrease my headaches. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is the easiest way to set flex items an equal height.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: stretch;
```

Comment: Please complete your answer. Also: `align-items: stretch` is the default, and `justify-content: center` should not affect item size. Please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

**Just add the following css**

```
ol {  
     display: -webkit-box; 
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-align: stretch;
     -webkit-align-items: stretch;
     -ms-flex-align: stretch;
     align-items: stretch;
     -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
     -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ol li {
     background: gold;
     padding: 5px 5px;
     margin: 5px 5px;
     width: 25% 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you explain the rationale behind it please?